# Overvoltage protection RS485 inputs

Tags: protection, rs485

The finished apparatus is supplied with 48V nominal ac (37V to 57V), and now I'm looking to design it so that it isn't destroyed if a technician accidentally connects the supply 48V +/- to the RS485 inputs.

I can't use reverse biased diodes to ground, since -5V is perfectly acceptable RS485 signal level.

Comment: The best solution to the problem is to provide a separate connector for supply, if that's an option. And always use "straight cables" where signal 1 goes to pin 1 and so on. Failing that, then maybe consider galvanic isolation of the bus.

Answer (score 4):

My advice is to use bidirectional zeners or TVS diodes and fuse the lines. If 48 volts is inappropriately applied, then the fuses burn to protect the zeners and, the zeners protect the circuit from over-voltage.

It's not ideal but at least you can change the fuses. You can get nice little SMD fuses and holders that might be suitable: -

[image]

Picture from [Farnell](https://uk.farnell.com/littelfuse/0154001-dr/fuse-smd-1a-omni-block-very-fast/dp/9943633).

Also, Analog Devices has got a good article on 485 protection methods [here](https://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/rs485-rs422-transceivers-operate-from-3v-to-55v-supplies-and-withstand-60v-faults.html) - it's entitled: -

> **RS485/RS422 Transceivers Operate from 3V to 5.5V Supplies and
> Withstand ±60V Faults**

Picture from the aforementioned document as an example: -

[image]

Comment: He'll get poor with GDTs and TBUs! I'd say that zeners and fuses should be enough. A SIDAC would also be good to punish the technician in changing the fuse

Comment: Thanks for your answers.
I have used a SM712 bidirectional TVS and 125mA fuses

Comment: @Mark83 [what you should consider doing next](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour). So, if you have your answer, follow the link to see what you need to do about completing the Q and A session OR, raise a new comment if something is a little unclear.